# Android Studio: Error:Execution failed for task

Tags: java, android, execution

This is a new installation for Android studio 2.3.3 on windows 10 64bit machine, android failed execution for first project, never worked, I tried all solutions here, delete cache, rebuild, clear project, reinstall Android, reinstall Java, environment variables, not using embedded JDK, changing project path what ever solution never worked with this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\myAccount.android\build-cache\6460e35c08ce39c08eb2823bfce76d67a31dcb77\output\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)

Gradle Module

[image: Gradle Module]

Gradle Project

[image: Gradle Project]

Comment: Try to delete your build file and rebuild .Hope it will solve your issue

Comment: thank you, didn't wok i deleted, and rebuild, same issue

Comment: @AhmedSalim did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Just delete 'C:\Users\myAccount.android\build-cache\6460e35c08ce39c08eb2823bfce76d67a31dcb77', and rebuild your project. Android Studio will recreate this folder.

Comment: Then Invalidate caches/restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in build.gradle file and rebuild project again;

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.user.packagename"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 25
    versionName "2.5"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' // will not include LICENSE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}
```

Comment: thank you, if you could be more specific please , i tried in both build.gradle append at the end , but another error .

Comment: No not in both gradle ...You have to paste this code in your specific app build.gradle  after buildTypes tag in android tag

Comment: didnt work, android {
 .
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' // will not include LICENSE file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

Comment: yes i ws downoloading the 25 version, but didnt work, i used your code with my package name but still same issue

Comment: is there any specific configuration for android studio on windows 10 64 bit, i downloded latest version for windows, already installed JDK 1.8 latest , this is not my first time install  ,  but first time in wndows 10 .64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, you helped me alot solve this issue 
Here is what happened, i traced that error , Android studio cannot find the file AndroidManifest.xml in the cash output folder, and actually it wasn't there, next step i deleted everything in the folder: C:\Users\myAccount.android\build-cache, and gave permission to the .Android folder, and deleted all old projects, cearte new project and the  AndroidManifest.xml is there, now im checking my app on my Samsung device, i revert all modification to default settings for Android Studio, and it is still fine ,  what i think is the deleting all file in cash solved the issue, i already did it before but may be it is multiple problem like missing SDK that i have installed ... thank you all hopefully somebody benefit from this

Answer (score 0):

Moving project files to ntfs drive fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, also moving my files from an exFAT drive to an NTFS one seemed to work

Answer (score -1):

you need to check for your minSDK if its not installed then you need to first installed the proper SDKs,and then everything worked fine.hope it will work for you.

Comment: did you try to refresh all gradle projects...if not(right hand side in android studio ->click on gradle->click on  refresh all gradle projects)....if this also not work show us your gradle file and AndroidManifest please

Comment: refresh, create new project, delete all old projects, same ,  check main question for my gradle